# Boot menu not showing

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit alongside Windows 7 32 bit, from official DVD image.

Ubuntu installer asked me to allocate ~80 GB space on my HD, which finished successfully same as whole installing process. Then I removed DVD press Enter and PC booted in Windows 7, not showing any boot option.

I had already installed Ubuntu along Windows in the past, and I was expecting boot menu on PC start.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your computer is finding the windows bootloader instead of grub (ubuntu bootloader). You may need to manually reinstall grub. What does your partition table look like? (Boot into live-cd, press try, search for/open gparted)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In the meantime I detected the problem - this PC had 2 hard disks and both had bootloaders. It seems that Windows 7 was installed on secondary HD while it bootloader was on first HD. After changing boot disk in bios from secondary to primary disk, Ubuntu boot menu showed correctly and I can boot in either Ubuntu or Windows 7 from there.

Comment: Ah yeah that would do it. I suspected that at first actually but in your question you made it sound like there was only one hard drive that was dual booted.